# Grails hibernate search returns copied instances

Tags: database, hibernate, grails

I have a domain class in Grails, which looks like the following:

```
class Tag implements Serializable {
    Long wallpaper
    String location, tag

    static mapping = {
        if (Environment.current != Environment.TEST) {
            table name: 'tag', schema: 'jws'
            id composite: ['wallpaper', 'location']

            columns {
                wallpaper column: 'wallpaper_id',       sqlType: 'INTEGER', length: 11
                location  column: 'wallpaper_location', sqlType: 'VARCHAR', length: 255
            }
        }

        tag column: 'tag', sqlType: 'VARCHAR', length: 255

        version(false)
    }

    static constraints = {
        wallpaper nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 11
        location  nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 255
        tag       nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 255
    }
}
```

The database contains the following data for a specific search result:

| wallpaper_id | wallpaper_location | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11660 | art | bookcase |
| 11660 | art | books |
| 11660 | art | cat |
| 11660 | art | chair |
| 11660 | art | isometric |
| 11660 | art | lamp |
| 11660 | art | men |
| 11660 | art | planetary rings |
| 11660 | art | planets |
| 11660 | art | plants |
| 11660 | art | reflection |
| 11660 | art | rug |
| 11660 | art | space |
| 11660 | art | telescope |
| 11660 | art | universe |

However, when I try the following query, I get 15 results (the amount of rows in the table), but only the first row (so I get 15 x '11660 | art | bookcase').

```
List<Tag> wt = (List<Tag>) Tag.createCriteria().list {
    eq('wallpaper', w.main_id)
    order('tag', 'asc')
}
```

The same exact issue happens with other wallpaper_id's as well.

I have tried to following to solve this problem:

1. Added eq('location', w.location) to the 'createCriteria().list{}' statement.
2. Used a view with a different table name (since the attribute 'tag' and table name 'tag' were the same).
3. Tried to retrieve every single tag from all wallpaper_id's with a '.list()'.
4. Refactored the 'tag' attribute to 'tagValue' in the Tag domain class.
5. Removed the 'order()' from the createCriteria.
6. Tried an HQL query (manual query via the executeQuery() method).
7. Deleted .build folder, cleaned the project.
8. Refreshed Gradle projects.

If anyone has any ideas as to what could cause this problem, please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine pointed me in the right direction: my domain class setup was wrong. The columns 'wallpaper_id', 'wallpaper_location' and 'tag' are all part of the same primary key, so the only thing I had to do was add the 'tag' attribute as a part of the primary key:

```
columns {
    wallpaper column: 'wallpaper_id',       sqlType: 'INTEGER', length: 11
    location  column: 'wallpaper_location', sqlType: 'VARCHAR', length: 255
    tag       column: 'tag',                sqlType: 'VARCHAR', length: 255 // This line is added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy. You will really really regret it using composite IDs with hibernate. They just do not work very well. For one thing, you will have to write a hashCode and equals method to your class, if you read the documentation. But that's problematic, because if you put your class into a collection (like maybe your Wallpaper class has a collection of tags), then what happens if the Wallpaper is a new object, it hasn't been assigned an ID yet, thus your hashes and equals don't work. There's just lots and lots of pain ahead of you, hours and days of testing and trying different incantations to make it work. I know you probably are reluctant to add a tag_id column, that you feel you don't need, but I really really recommend when using hibernate, just bite the bullet and always have a plain regular integer column as the primary key. You don't have to pay attention to it. Just have it auto generated, and ignore it.